# Graphing a sinusoid in Matlab.

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I need to graph/plot this sinusoid in Matlab. I have no idea how to set it up in Matlab. I am new to Matlab and have had little to no experience coding in matlab. Any help would he great! It's question 1. 
[image]

The picture below is my attempt to graph in matlab. 
[image]

This is an example I referenced.
[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far ? Please understand that MSE is not a homework solving site .

Comment: Just use A=3 on line 1 and instead of 3A, which is an error in line 4, use A.

Comment: Are you sure $x(t)=3 \cos (w_0-\frac{\pi}{4})$ is not a typo. Perhaps it was meant $x(t)=3 \cos (w_0 t-\frac{\pi}{4})$., otherwise for a given $w_0$ you’ll be plotting a constant function.  In terms of matlab, $3A$ is not allowed sense matlab doesn’t know that means multiplication. You need to write out $3*A$. Also $x(t)=....$ in this situation doesn’t make sense. In matlab $x(1)$ is the first element of vector $x$ and $x(2)$ is the second element. Since t=-10 -9....20, $x(-10)$ doesn’t make any sense. Just write $x=..$ and plot(t,x)